# Beautifulsoup code no longer working in python script

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a python script that I am having trouble with and I think I have narrowed the issue down to this line:

```
formkey = soup.find_all("script")[9].string[153:][:-141]
```

I believe that this line is supposed to return the value of "form_key" on this page https://shop.adidas.ae/en/forum-mis-wrap-shoes/BY4412.html

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[153:-141]`? Why two different slices?

Comment: `script[9]` is `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en"></script>` There's no `form_key` in there.

Comment: The only place I see `form_key` is in two URLs and `<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="lHz0KKUAm0gU3nL0" />`

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I think it refers to 

`<script type="text/javascript">
    truncateOptions();
    decorateList('cart-sidebar', 'none-recursive');
    $j('document').ready(function () {
        var minicartOptions = {
            formKey: "oDPKFYizNvqu71p9",
            checkout_data_layer: {"actionField":{"step":1},"products":[]}        };
        Mini = new Minicart(minicartOptions);
        Mini.init();
    });
</script>`

Comment: That's `script[14]`, not `script[9]`. But it doesn't have `form_key` in it. Ahh, it has `formKey`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the value of input with `name="form_key"`

do:

```
form_key_value = soup.find('input', {'name':'form_key'})['value']
```

Looking at the source of the page, this value is what you want and it is easier to get it this way and also more Pythonic than to parse the JavaScript

Comment: Welcome to SO ! - You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You should use BeautifulSoup to find elements and then regex (`re`) to parse text inside your target elements. Like this:

```
import re, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

regex = re.compile(r'formKey:\s*"(.*)"')

r = requests.get('https://shop.adidas.ae/en/forum-mis-wrap-shoes/BY4412.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
scripts = soup.find_all("script")

all_of_them = [None if match is None else match.groups() for match in [regex.search(script.text) for script in scripts]]
just_the_matches = [match.groups() for match in [regex.search(script.text) for script in scripts] if script is not None]
```

The results:

```
>>> all_of_them
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, (u'U53YNK8paAE4Cdij',), None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> just_the_matches
[(u'U53YNK8paAE4Cdij',)]
```

**Important:**

- Do not make assumptions, such as "it's the 10th script" or "the data I want is exactly between characters XXX and YYY".
- If they add a script, your program is broken. You don't want that.
- If they change a bit of this 10th script, your program is broken. You don't want that.
- Try to always think of how to make your program more robust to external perturbations.

**Also:**

- As @alexisdevarennes puts it, if you can have the data in several places, try to retrieve it from the easiest place (or the most robust place).